# How do I set a div to take up the remaining space available based on the parent's div without wrapping?

Tags: html, css

I have 8 div's side by side using float:left.  Each of them have a certain set width.  What I would like to do is have the last div take up the remaining width available.

for example,

If i have a parent div width of 810px.

I'm setting the first 7 divs up with 100px.  However the last one I would like to be automatically calculated to 110px.  The reason being is if a scrollbar appears, this div gets wrapped to the next line.  I do not want it to wrap.

Comment: You are aware that depending on theme, window manager et al a scrollbar might one day be 15, 25 or even 50 pixels wide?

Comment: Yep, thats why I have allocated 110px in this example depending on the width of the scrollbar.

Comment: If you use CSS3 you could do something like `width: calc(100% - 700px);` Otherwise it is kind of difficult I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern browsers only:

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div class="last">8</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
background: red;
}

.content div {
-webkit-flex-basis: 50px;
margin: 5px;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-grow: 0;
flex-grow: 0;
}

.content .last {
-webkit-flex-grow: 1;
flex-grow: 1;
background: blue;
color: white;
}
```

And [the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MpH47/)..

Answer (score 0):

You could use calc() if you don't need to support < IE 9 or non-webkit-based versions of Opera.

```
#lastObject {
  width: calc(100% - 700px);
}
```

Of course that assumes each div is 100px and you have seven of them.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CgNAn/2/

(Also, the divs can't wrap for this to work, let me know if that's an issue)

Answer (score -2):

just put all 8 divs in one big div with a fixed width and do the math so they all stay their width.